# SSL certificate for both www and non-www

Tags: ssl-certificate

I bought a SSL certificate from Globalsign (AlphaSSl). According to their site, all certificates secures both www and non-www.

But when I go to https://www.kanzan.se, I get invalid SSL certificate (only valid for kanzan.se).

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain isn't loading for me, but, did you specify www.kanzan.se as a SubjectAlternativeName on the certificate request, or use the wildcard function?

https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1674632-add-or-remove-subject-alternative-names

Comment: Yes, this is possible too. Some certificate issuers don't add the www. hostname automatically, and require you to specify it explicitly.

Comment: Correct. AlphaSSL requires the SubjectAlternativeName to be specified in the CSR `subjectAltName=DNS:example.com,DNS:www.example.com`. if using openssl.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't do anything wrong; AlphaSSL did. Your certificate is only valid for kanzan.se, and not www.kanzan.se. Contact them to have the certificate fixed.

[image: Certificate Viewer: kanzan.se]

Comment: I added www.kanzan.se as a A record to the DNS, could that help?

Comment: @user2908112 It doesn't make any difference. The problem is that the certificate never included www.kanzan.se. It must be reissued.